How to change default settings for STL export (new one, not legacy)
TLDR: How to change a default settings to (new, not legacy) STL export?
Before Blender 4.0 there was an STL import/export script where we could change default settings (\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py)
On Blender 4.0 they added a second STL script and in Blender 4.1 it is now a default one and the old script is now named 'legacy'
I can still change the settings of 'legacy' but I can't find a file of the new STL script (unless it's \AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\presets\operator\wm.stl_export\__pycache__\Default.cpython-311.pyc - wich I don't think we can change)

Some of the importer/exporters have been rewritten in C++ rather than python for speed. That may be the case for this one.

Ok, so for now it is not possible to change default settings? Or is it hidden somewhere in some 'main' file with all rewritten exporters

No idea I'm afraid. Anything in the Blender manual? I've never used that format but it looks as if you can add Operator presets (top-right) with the '+' key in the file selector which presumably will be saved automatically.

In manual I only found a new operator name bpy.ops.wm.stl_export but it ave me nothing
Operator presets changed nothing, I still would need to select this preset so I can just click on the 'selected only'
Anywa, thx for answers :)

I haven't found a way to definitely change default settings but if your need is to be able to one click open an export window with custom settings, you can do it using a keymap :

Create a keymap to the export STL action, with a right click on File -> Export -> STL (.stl) :

Specify default export values in Edit -> Preferences menu, in the Keymap tab, for the entry Window -> Export STL :



Thanks
Maybe it will be even better than changing default values
I used a search bar for fast export but exporting through a shortcut is even faster (just need to remember the key and to add it again after an update)
I installed an 'Is key Free' addon to check what keys I can use. Took 'ctrl+ down arrow' for exporting to STL

That was extra helpful. HUGE thanks for the tip.
